# Make image relative to text length

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do this for my twitch, I have an image 1600x400 or something like that, it's background of my alert, so if the length of nickname changes, the background width changes relatively, but what I'm trying to do is cut image horizontally if text length changes
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy3Ql.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add some of your code to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much about the details of your code, this is what I can provide:

You can attempt to set the css as such:

```
#element{
    background-image: url('your/image/url.jpg');
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1k4aqz13/

Please reply with more detail so we can better answer your question.

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what i needed

Comment: @Hakko Dub Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with setting the `background-image` set to image along with `background-repeat:no-repeat;` and most importantly set the display to either inline-table or inline-block so that the element wraps around it's inner content.

Here is a sample code.

```css
#container{
  width: 100%;
}

.textContainer{
  background-image:url('http://placehold.it/350x100');
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  /*Uncomment below if you want the image to stretch only when text in div goes beyond the image width-wise.*/
  /*background-size:cover;*/ 

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="textContainer">
    This is some test text here.
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="textContainer">
    This is some test text here too to check.
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.